# IBAction gets stuck in Loop

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Ok, I have an IBAction that syncs with iCal and is also triggered by KVO of the 'name' property in my CD Model, so that when the property changes the Action is triggered. What happens is that once the IBAction reaches the end it skips to the KVO declaration which then triggers the Action again and again and again, this is where the loop occurs.

Here's some code. The IBAction …

```
- (IBAction)sync:(id)sender {
    [syncButton setTitle:@"Syncing..."];
    NSString *dateText = (@"Last Sync : %d", [NSDate date]);
    [syncDate setStringValue:dateText];
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription
                                              entityForName:@"projects" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setEntity:entityDescription];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *array = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (array == nil)
    {
        NSAlert *anAlert = [NSAlert alertWithError:error];
        [anAlert runModal];
    }
    NSArray *namesArray = [array valueForKey:@"name"];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [CalCalendarStore taskPredicateWithCalendars:[[CalCalendarStore defaultCalendarStore] calendars]];
    NSArray *tasksNo = [[CalCalendarStore defaultCalendarStore] tasksWithPredicate:predicate];
    NSArray *tasks = [tasksNo valueForKey:@"title"];
    NSMutableArray *namesNewArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:namesArray];
    [namesNewArray removeObjectsInArray:tasks];
    NSLog(@"%d", [namesNewArray count]);    
    NSInteger *popIndex = [calenderPopup indexOfSelectedItem];

    //Load the array
    CalCalendarStore *store = [CalCalendarStore defaultCalendarStore];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *supportDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fileName = [supportDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"oldtasks.plist"];

    NSMutableArray *oldTasks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileName];
    [oldTasks removeObjectsInArray:namesArray];
    NSLog(@"%d",[oldTasks count]);
    //Use the content
    NSPredicate* taskPredicate = [CalCalendarStore taskPredicateWithCalendars:[[CalCalendarStore defaultCalendarStore] calendars]];
    NSArray* allTasks = [[CalCalendarStore defaultCalendarStore] tasksWithPredicate:taskPredicate];

    // Get the calendar
    CalCalendar *calendar = [[store calendars] objectAtIndex:popIndex];
    // Note: you can change which calendar you're adding to by changing the index or by
    // using CalCalendarStore's -calendarWithUID: method    

        // Loop, adding tasks
    for(NSString *title in namesNewArray) {
        // Create task
        CalTask *task = [CalTask task];
        task.title = title;
        task.calendar = calendar;

        // Save task
        if(![[CalCalendarStore defaultCalendarStore] saveTask:task error:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Error");
            // Diagnostic error handling
            NSAlert *anAlert = [NSAlert alertWithError:error];
            [anAlert runModal];
    }
    } 

    NSMutableArray *tasksNewArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:tasks];
    [tasksNewArray removeObjectsInArray:namesArray];
    NSLog(@"%d", [tasksNewArray count]);    
    for(NSString *title in tasksNewArray) {
        NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];
        JGManagedObject *theParent = 
        [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"projects"
                                      inManagedObjectContext:moc];
        [theParent setValue:nil forKey:@"parent"];
        // This is where you add the title from the string array
        [theParent setValue:title forKey:@"name"]; 
        [theParent setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:@"position"];

    }

    for(CalTask* task in allTasks)
        if([oldTasks containsObject:task.title]) {
            [store removeTask:task error:nil];
        }

    // Create a predicate for an array of names.
    NSPredicate *mocPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name IN %@", oldTasks];
    [request setPredicate:mocPredicate];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];

    // Execute the fetch request put the results into array
    NSArray *resultArray = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (resultArray == nil)
    {
        // Diagnostic error handling
        NSAlert *anAlert = [NSAlert alertWithError:error];
        [anAlert runModal];
    }

    // Enumerate through the array deleting each object.
    // WARNING, this will delete everything in the array, so you may want to put more checks in before doing this.
    for (JGManagedObject *objectToDelete in resultArray ) {
        // Delete the object.
        [moc deleteObject:objectToDelete];
    }
    //Save the array
    [namesArray writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES];
    [syncButton setTitle:@"Sync Now"];
    NSLog(@"Sync Completed");
}
```

Which when it reaches the end (somehow) triggers the KVO Declaration …

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    [self performSelector:@selector(sync:)];
}
```

Which then triggers the IBAction again. This is where the loop occurs as it gets stuck here and constantly triggers the Action.

**Can anyone figure out what on earth is happening???**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are triggering the selector `sync:` for any KVO-compliant property.
You should filter any keypath that gets changed withing your sync method to avoid recursion.

I would do the following:

- Set a breakpoint and check the value
  of keyPath to figure out which change
  is starting the recursion.
- Filter out changes for keypaths that trigger a recursion

or

- Detach all observers when sync: starts and reattach them when finished

Comment: +1 Not a bad idea to detach all observers at the top of sync and reattach them at the bottom. That way, changes made during sync aren't observed, but changes to the model or the calendar store will still trigger a sync.

Comment: So do you suggest that at the start of the action I add `[JGManagedObject removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"name"];` and at the end add `[JGManagedObject addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"name" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];`?

Comment: Joshua: Those aren't class methods, so sending those messages to the class won't work.

Comment: How else would I do it? In the JGManagedObject I send the messages to `self`.

Comment: You send the messages to the object you're observing (i.e., the one you want to stop observing and then start observing again).

Comment: That IS the object I am observing. I am observing `JGManagedObject` and the Observer is The App Delegate.

Comment: I've tried adding `[JGManagedObject removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"name"];` at the start and `[JGManagedObject addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"name" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];` at the end, it works flawlessly the first time but then it says it can't remove the observer because it isn't observing even though I added it again at the end of the action.

Comment: So, JGManagedObject is the name of a variable containing a pointer to an instance, *not* the name of a class? Normally, <initials>[adjective]<noun> is the name of a class. If it's the name of a variable, I suggest you rename it to avoid future confusion.

Comment: No, It's a class but it's what I am observing because in the NSManagedObject sub-class called JGManagedObject I have the code 
`- (void) awakeFromInsert {
 [self addObserver:[NSApp delegate] forKeyPath:@"name" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
}`

Comment: @Joshua - you may be calling `self` from within your `JGManagedObject` class file, but that actually means you're calling it on an instance of the class. You can't send instance methods such as `removeObserver:forKeyPath:` on a class object, you need to send it to an actual instance of the class.

Comment: How do I send it to an instance of the class?