# removeObserver:forKeyPath: in dealloc

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, key-value-observing, dealloc

If my instance is observing some property of another object, am I supposed to call removeObserver:forKeyPath: in dealloc?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes**

...unless there is a more appropriate time earlier in execution.

Observers are held as nonretained references. Failing to un-register can result in your deallocated instance being messaged.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use -removeObserver:forKeyPath: to remove the observer before -[NSObject dealloc] runs, so yes, doing it in the -dealloc method of your class would work.
refer this questions.
[Removing an Observer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564540/removing-an-observer)
[question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927/in-cocoa-do-i-need-to-remove-an-object-from-receiving-kvo-notifications-when-dea)